# how can i make an html list in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I want to make a list in HTML and then the user selects the list and then do something with the selections.

For example. List of fruits. Apple bannana, grapes.

User selects grapes and if grapes is selected asked how many grapes?

I would like to know how i can do this in Javascript or Jquery

Comment: What have you tried? Could you post the code you have written so far?

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Use this code block. As simple as that,

```js
//generates the list
var items = 'Apple, bannana, grapes';
var nHtml = '';
items = items.split(',');
items.forEach(function(v){
   //trim() will remove the blank spaces
   nHtml+='<li>'+ v.trim() +'</li>';
});
$('#itemList').append('<ul>'+ nHtml +'</ul>');

//detect click on the list item
$('li').click(function(){
   var name = $(this).text();
   var question = 'How many '+name+' ?';
   $('#question').html('<span>'+ question +'</span><input type="text" id="answer" />')
});

//get the number feed into the text box
function getCount(){
  var answer = $('#answer').val();
  console.log(answer);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='itemList'></div>
<div id='question'></div>
<button onclick='getCount()'>Get Count</button>
```